# How to import only new data by using Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, import, hdfs, rdbms, sqoop

Let me give an example: I exported 1TB of data yesterday. Today, the database got another 1GB of data. If I try to import the data again today, Sqoop will import 1TB+1GB of data, then I am merging it. So it's a headache. I want to import only new data and append it to the old data. In this way, on a daily basis, I'll pull the RDBMS data into HDFS.

Answer (score 4):

You can use sqoop Incremental Imports:

Sqoop provides an `incremental import` mode which can be used to retrieve only rows newer than some previously-imported set of rows.

Incremental import arguments:

`--check-column (col)`  Specifies the column to be examined when determining which rows to import.
`--incremental (mode)`  Specifies how Sqoop determines which rows are new. Legal values for mode include append and last modified.

`--last-value (value)`  Specifies the maximum value of the check column from the previous import.

**Reference:** https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports

**For Incremental Import:** You would need to specify a value in a check column against a reference value for the most recent import. For example, if the `–incremental` append argument was specified, along with `–check-column id and –last-value 100`, all rows with id > 100 will be imported. If an incremental import is run from the command line, the value which should be specified as `–last-value` in a subsequent incremental import will be printed to the screen for your reference. If an incremental import is run from a saved job, this value will be retained in the saved job. Subsequent runs of `sqoop job –exec` some Incremental Job will continue to import only newer rows than those previously imported.

For importing all the tables at one go, you would need to use sqoop-import-all-tables command, but this command must satisfy the below criteria to work

Each table must have a single-column primary key.
You must intend to import all columns of each table.
You must not intend to use non-default splitting column, nor impose any conditions via a WHERE clause.

**Reference:** https://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/sqoop-incremental-import/